# Why this error when a site collection is deleted and a new one created?

Tags: site-collection

Here is the error I receive

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Date: Fri, 21 Dec 2012 10:42:47 GMT
Connection: close
```

What is the problem and what can i do about it?

Comment: Can you provide us with a little more information-- background, environment, specifics?

Comment: Is it happening with the PowerShell too? ULS logs?